# Assassination missions dissapeared after completing the game

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I completed the game with Option C

> So that I could have all the characters survive

but now when I try to do the assassinations that I saved to the end for bigger profits, they do not show up on the mini map. They are not available to do and I have no idea on what to do.

How can I play the missed Assassination missions?

Answer (score 1):

You have to be working as Franklin for the missions to show up - if you're Franklin and there's no green L on the map, then you may have discovered a bug.